# passing javascript object array to ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is my imple code on submit of form. Where I want to insert table data values in database through ajax. But it's not going to controller.

```
$('#submit').click(function(){

 var TableData = new Array();
 $('#cart_details tr').each(function(row, tr){

 TableData[row]={
    "productname" : $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text()
    , "quantity" :$(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text()
    , "unit" : $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text()
    , "unit_rate" : $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text()
  }

   });


TableData.shift();

//TableData = $.toJSON(TableData);
var TableData = JSON.stringify(TableData);

alert(TableData);
var followurl='<?php echo base_url()."index.php/purchase/save_product";?>';

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",                     
   url:followurl,                                                 
   data: TableData,
   datatype : "json",

   cache: false,
   success: function (data) {
     alert("dsad"+data);
   }
   });

  });
```

When I stringify tabledata array output is like this..

```
  [{"productname":"Copper Sulphate","quantity":"1","unit":"1","unit_rate":"100"},
  {"productname":"Hypta Hydrate","quantity":"1","unit":"1","unit_rate":"100"}]
```

My question is why it's not going to controller? it's because of array object or something else??

**Tabledata is javascript object array . Am I right??**

Comment: echo `followurl` and check it...

Comment: already checked it..and it's correct

Comment: what is your error? Have you checked at php side? Is it ok?

Comment: It's not going to controller then how do I check php side

Comment: the best way is to use http://xdebug.org/ I use netbeans with xDebug.

Comment: or you can go to network properties in Chrome inspect element and check the values ajax is sending to php

Comment: What does your PHP code processing the form look like?

Comment: I just called a function in purchase controller on ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$.ajax({
```

instead of

```
$.post({
```

use this code

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",                     
   url:followurl,                                                 
   data: {TableData : TableData},
   cache: false,
   success: function (data) {
     alert("dsad"+data);
   }
   });
```

check the Documentation [jquery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

The syntax for `$.post` is

```
$(selector).post(URL,data,function(data,status,xhr),dataType)
```

You don't have to define the type ,

but here you are using the `$.ajax` mixing with `$.post`

this is the `$.ajax` function syntax

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

SO change the `$.post` to `$.ajax` and try

Comment: From what I remember, both will do the same thing, I am waiting for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), you can pass an object to `data`. I think you'd make things easier and simpler for you if you followed that approach.

```
...
//TableData = $.toJSON(TableData); NO!!!
//var TableData = JSON.stringify(TableData); NO!!!

//alert(TableData);
var followurl='<?php echo base_url()."index.php/purchase/save_product";?>';

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",                     
   url:followurl,                                                 
   data: { 
    dataTable: TableData
   },
   datatype : "json",
   cache: false,
   success: function (data) {
     alert(data);
   }
   });

});
```

Very simple example (without validation or anything of the kind) of `index.php/purchase/save_product`

```
$data = $_POST["dataTable"];
echo $data[0]["productname"];// Sending back the productName of the first element received.
die();
```

As you can see, you could access data in your `index.php/purchase/save_product` file very easily if you followed this approach.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hi It look like you are using some CMS or Framework. Can you please let us know which framework or CMS you are using. I would then be able to sort out this issue. It looks like you are using Code Ignitor. If its so then i hope this would help you

```
$.post( "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/purchase/save_product", function(data) {
  alert( "success" );
}, 'html') // here specify the datatype
.fail(function() {
  alert( "error" );
})
```

in Your case your ajax call must look like

```
var followurl="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/purchase/save_product";

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",                     
   url:followurl,                                                 
   data: TableData,
   datatype : "json",

   cache: false,
   success: function (data) {
     alert("dsad"+data);
   }
   });

  });
```

> Error Seems to be in your **followUrl** please try using as its in mine code